# Searching for a number in a given array using pointers

Tags: c++

I need to create a program that searches for a user inserted number from an array using pointers. This is my current code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FindNumber(int *ptrArr, int size, int *ptr1) {
    for (int *p = ptrArr; p < ptrArr + size; ++p) {
        if (ptrArr[*p] == *ptr1) {
            cout << "Number (" << *ptr1 << ") found in the array with an index of: " << *p;
            break;
        }

        if (*p == size) {
            cout  << "No such number in given array\n";
        } 

    }
}

int main () {
    int numbers[10] = {5, 4, 7, 10, 24, 15, 8, 2, 9, 13};
    int num;

    cout << "What number do you want to search for?\n";
    cin >> num;

    FindNumber(numbers, sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int), &num);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with for loop, but I don't know what it is
Sometimes it finds the number with right index, sometimes it doesn't find it even though there is that particular number in the array, sometimes it finds the number but outputs the wrong index

```
What number do you want to search for?
7
No such number in given array
Number (7) found in the array with an index of: 2

What number do you want to search for?
5
No such number in given array
```

Tried changing the for loop on my own but no successo. Hoping for some help.

Comment: `ptrArr[*p]` please explain what you think this particular piece of code does

Comment: @UnholySheep compares the current number in the loop with the one that user has inserted?

Comment: You generally seem to be somehow under the impression that `int *p = ptrArr` somehow writes an index into what `p` points at. Which is completely wrong, `p` refers to elements of the array, not any index

Comment: @levaldssandis `*p` is already the element in the array. Since this is the case, it is not clear what you meant by `if (*p == size)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 small typos in your code.

-No need to index the array with "*p"

-The index need to be calculated by subtracting p from the original pointer.

Please see here the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FindNumber(int* ptrArr, int size, int* ptr1) {
    for (int* p = ptrArr; p < ptrArr + size; ++p) {
        if (*p == *ptr1) {
            cout << "Number (" << *ptr1 << ") found in the array with an index of: " << (p-ptrArr);
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "No such number in given array\n";

}

int main() {
    int numbers[10] = { 5, 4, 7, 10, 24, 15, 8, 2, 9, 13 };
    int num;

    cout << "What number do you want to search for?\n";
    cin >> num;

    FindNumber(numbers, sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int), &num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're iterating though the array with a pointer, you just dereference the pointer to access the current element instead of using the `[]` operator on the pointer. For determining the index, you can use `std::distance`

```
void FindNumber(int *const ptrArr, int size, int const* const ptr1)
{
    for (int* pos = ptrArr; pos != ptrArr + size; ++pos)
    {
        if (*pos == *ptr1) { // compare element at the current position with input
            cout << "Number (" << *ptr1 << ") found in the array with an index of: " << std::distance(ptrArr, pos) << '\n';
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout  << "No such number in given array\n";
}
```

If you aren't allowed to use `std::distance`, you can replace

```
std::distance(ptrArr, pos)
```

with

```
(pos - ptrArr)
```

Note: You should avoid pointers, if possible. There's no point in passing the third parameter as pointer. Furthermore this kind of logic is already available in the `<algorithm>` standard library header.

```
void FindNumber(int *const ptrArr, int size, int value)
{
    auto const end = ptrArr + size;
    auto const pos = std::find(ptrArr, end, value);
    
    if (pos == end)
    {
        std::cout  << "No such number in given array\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Number (" << value << ") found in the array with an index of: " << std::distance(ptrArr, pos) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate. I have to use the pointers just for the exercise. Mind if I ask what pointers are actually useful for? Since I am just getting my brain messed up with them and see no point of an actual usage of them.

Comment: @levaldssandis It's appropriate to use pointers, to pass (the first element of) an array. At a low level you often need to use pointers to be able info about dynamically allocated data. Usually you should use classes that already take care of the pointer logic under the hood though, e.g. `std::vector`, or classes that at least help with memory management, like `std::unique_ptr`. Basically given a type `T` for single elements prefer the use of the following types: `T` (if `T` is cheap to copy), `T const&`, `T&`, and if none of those do the trick, then using a pointer may indeed be required.

Comment: `std::vector` internally uses ponters btw and `std::unique_ptr` is basically just a wrapper around a raw pointer (with the exception of non-default deleters which are rarely used).